# Facing issue after upgrade to .NET 6 from .NET Framework

Tags: wpf, telerik, .net-6.0

I have upgraded WPF application to .NET. Application was developed in .NET 4.5 framework.
Used Telerik controls. But now the issue is this: While I'm running the application, it doesn't show any controls after the application runs.

[image]

Comment: "I have upgraded WPF application to .Net." Presumably you mean that you have upgraded to a specific version of .Net. Is that the latest version? Do you see your controls at any point? Have you debugged throught he constructor to make sure those controls are being created?

Comment: How are you getting the Telerik Controls?  If you are using the installed ones, I strongly suggest that you stop and instead use the Telerik NuGet Server to retrieve that.   That's what we did when we updated from .NET FW.  https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/getting-started/telerik-application-lifecycle/nuget-application-lifecyle

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the correct dlls.